# How to simulate selection on AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android

I have an AutoCompleteTextView object with the name myAutoCompleteTextView.

```
myAutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView,      int position, long id) {
        //do something
   }
}
```

Now I try to simulate a specific selection of an item on it like that:

```
myAutoCompleteTextView.setText("some item from the array of this AutoCompleteTextView");
```

The result is that I see the required item in the AutoCompleteTextView,
but nothing happens. Only the text shown over there.
When the user choose manually  the item everythings is fine.

Can someone help me how can I simulate a selection?

Answer (score 0):

I gues u call a function or something in your onItemClick function.
why dont u just call this code outside your listener ? Or am I missing something here?

something like

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    MyObject myObject = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    doStuffWithObject(myObject);
```

}

And u can call the function outside your adapter with any reference.
Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: The function inside onItemClick() that will be called, depends on the selected item. in myAutoCompleteTextView.setText(...) I want every time to pass another argument..

Answer (score 0):

This code as well as place the same order:

```
codselect.CommandText = "select* from team where nome Like '" + TextBox2.Text + "%'"
```